# MySQL equivalent of SQL Server syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new on MySQL. I have below SQL Query and trying convert into mysql to give a default value for a date column in the table create script.

```
(date_add(second,(-1),sysutcdatetime()))
```

But it doesn't support in mysql. Getting below error.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near '(-1),sysutcdatetime()))' at line 1

Also I need to get the date in this format '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably does what you want:

```
now() - interval 1 second
```

However, if you do specifically want UTC, then:

```
utc_timestamp() - interval 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(sysutcdatetime, INTERVAL -1 second);
```

**Example:**

> ```
> SELECT now(),DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 second);
> ```

> | now() | DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 second) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-03-17 11:43:32 | 2021-03-17 11:43:31 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=22338f44134cb0699ef52c6f86603f35)*